# How to make my images and div responsive to screen size

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem. My title div changes in response to the width of the page. However, the images in the div will float to the left or stack upon each other. How do I make it so that they resize automatically and stay centered in the page?

```
`<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="active-text"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li id="logo"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="products">
        <a href=''><img src='http://g04.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1snhcKVXXXXXZXpXXq6xXFXXXN/WB1363-font-b-Korean-b-font-font-b-Style-b-font-font-b-Fashion-b-font.jpg' alt='' width='200px' height='320px'></a>
        <a href=''><img src='http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1pkBKIXXXXXaGXFXXq6xXFXXXZ/2015-prefall-autumn-winter-middle-age-Fashion-font-b-mature-b-font-font-b-lady-b.jpg' alt='' width='200px' height='320px'></a>
        <a href=''><img src='http://image.rakuten.co.jp/mountain-hop/cabinet/04035967/04654733/da1512-0005-01.jpg' alt='' width='200px' height='320px'></a>
        <a href=''><img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9iiobsGOL-7tKsLqf4luH-W4yaoEBnx1yFxEkE1FNJHoAL2YL' alt='' width='200px' height='320px'></a>
    </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; <?= date('Y'); ?> Chongqibao Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`


    html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    background: url(coffee.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


.box {
    border: 1px red dashed;
}

#title {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #efefef;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    border: 7px solid #efefef;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    height: 58px;

}

#logo {
    float:right;
}

#logo a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.active {
    background-color: white;
}

#active-text a {
    color: black;
}

.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;

    color: white;
}

.nav ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: black;
}

.products {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.products img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 20px;
    padding:5;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use responsive css. It allows you to set `@media (max-width: 500px) {}` or `@media (min-width: 500px) {}` and put the css for styling elements at those screen-sizes inside.

This allows you to change specific or all properties of the elements depending on what you put inside of the responsive `@media` tags.

Here is the W3Schools webpage on it: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Taylor's answer that it will not work on smaller screen sizes unless you have a

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>
```

in the head of your html code. This will then allow your @media code in your css to actually adapt to the other sizes.

This site will also help you to determine proper widths in your @media code.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing some pixel-calculations:

Use Viewport units: `vw, vh, vmin, vmax` over `px, pt, ...`

https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

i.e. `50vw` will always be 50% of the devices viewport width.

Comment: It still didn't work. I guess what I'm trying to make responsive is my "products" div that contains all the image's. I'm using safari. Once I start extending the window horizontally all the image's get pushed to the left while my "title" div actually resizes itself.